# How to get the dropdown list box text using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I get the dropdown list box selected text value, and find the source of the function calling(where from the function was called).

```
<div ng-controller="cntrl">
<select id="dflfnt"  ng-change="opfun()" ng-model='mddl1' ng-options='option.value as option.name for option in ddl1Options.data'> 
</select>

<select id="3dfnt" ng-model='mddl2' ng-change="opfun()" ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in ddl2option.data">

</select>
</div>

<script>
function cntrl($scope)
{
$scope.ddl1Options={
data:[
{value:"Georgia, serif",name:"Style 1"},
{value:"'Palatino Linotype', 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, serif",name:"Style 2"}
]};

$scope.ddl2option={
data:[
{value:"font-effect-anaglyph",name:"anaglyph"},
{value:"font-effect-brick-sign",name:"brick-sign"},
{value:"font-effect-canvas-print",name:"canvas-print"},
{value:"font-effect-crackle",name:"crackle"}
]};


    $scope.opfun=function(){            
        alert($scope.mddl1); // Here I can get the value only
    }

}
</script>
```

In above I want to know where from the **opfun()** is trigger and get the selected text of the dropdownlistbox.

I am tried to get the text like below.

```
alert($scope.ddl2option.data[0].name);
```

But it was display always selected index.

Comment: you should use `$watch` instead of the change callback.

Comment: @Raphael Muller May I know the difference of $watch and ng-change

Comment: with `$watch`, you can listen to changes to your model in your controller, without having to add some code on the client side, i.e. in your html. this is good, since you want the changes of the model and do something in your controller. if your interface changes you don't have to change all client code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not totally sure what you're after but try removing `option.value` from your `ng-options` directive.

Is that what you are aiming for ..

Also, you should really consider changing your variable names to something more readable because it makes it really difficult to figure out what is going on with such cryptic variable names.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/d9NmQiQPTSEMNbwajYkp?p=preview)

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('cntrl', cntrl);


function cntrl($scope){

  $scope.ddl1Options = {
    data:[
      {value:"Georgia, serif", name:"Style 1"},
      {value:"'Palatino Linotype', 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, serif", name:"Style 2"}
    ]
  };

  $scope.mddl1 = $scope.ddl1Options.data[0];

  $scope.ddl2option = {
    data:[
      {value:"font-effect-anaglyph",name:"anaglyph"},
      {value:"font-effect-brick-sign",name:"brick-sign"},
      {value:"font-effect-canvas-print",name:"canvas-print"},
      {value:"font-effect-crackle",name:"crackle"}
    ]

  };

  $scope.mddl2 = $scope.ddl2option.data[0];


  $scope.opfun = function(selectedModelValue){            
      //alert(selectedModelValue); // Here I can get the value only
  }

}
```

**index.html**

```
  <select 
    id="dflfnt"  
    ng-change="opfun(mddl1)" 
    ng-model='mddl1' 
    ng-options='option.name for option in ddl1Options.data'
  ></select>

  <select 
    id="3dfnt" 
    ng-model='mddl2' 
    ng-change="opfun(mddl2)" 
    ng-options="option.name for option in ddl2option.data"
  ></select>

  <h5>mddl1</h5>
  <pre>{{mddl1}}</pre>

  <h5>mddl2</h5>
  <pre>{{mddl2}}</pre>

</div>
```

Comment: I want to access it from controller method.

Comment: You can. It's passed into the opfun function. I commented out the alert because it was annoying. You will just see [object] [object] as it is so put .value or .name to see a string.

Comment: Please tell me, why the following code doesn't executed. But your works fine http://plnkr.co/edit/OBzhWQwh86Q7DkFVkDmS?p=preview

Comment: Remove the option.value from your ng-options directive as before. You are using 'select as label for value in array' syntax which binds the 'select' part to your model. In your case that means you are assigning the 'value' property when I think you want the whole object. Spend some time reading the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions they aren't great but it's the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I got you a working [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/KS9J0pzAnwje6fZuNeuV?p=preview) with the `$watch` directive.

your html is no a little bit lighter:

```
<select 
    id="dflfnt"   
    ng-model='mddl1' 
    ng-options='option.name for option in ddl1Options.data'
  ></select>

  <select 
    id="3dfnt" 
    ng-model='mddl2' 
    ng-options="option.name for option in ddl2option.data"
  ></select>
```

and your controller has full control over if the model changes:

```
$scope.$watch('mddl1', function(mddl1) {
    console.log(mddl1);
});
```

if you want to watch booth togheter, just use:

```
$scope.$watch('mddl1 + mddl2', function(value) {
   //but note this value is concatenated
   console.log(value);

   //you should access the values over the $scope.mddln now
});
```